# How to use ContourPlot and illustrate the domain of its separate lines over one axis as continuous lines on the top?

Tags: plotting, precision-and-accuracy

I am using this code

```
f := Cos[3 x] + ((1 + 2 x Cot[2 x] - x Cos[y] Csc[x] Sec[x]) Sin[ 3 x])/(2 x);
g := Cos[3 x] + (2 Sin[3 x])/ x + (Cos[2 x] - Cos[y]) Csc[2 x] Sin[3 x] -  Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[ 3 x] + ((2 + x Cot[2 x] - x Cos[y] Csc[2 x]) Sin[3 x])/x)^2];

ContourPlot[f == g, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 1, 3}, FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 70]
```

> How can I modify the `ContourPlot` code so that it shows me the values of those separate lines over $x$ as continuous lines on the top of the plot? However, it seems that I need to increase the precision of the plot, but increasing it, will result in a long process time.

I mean something like this (I did this manually, so, it is not accurate.)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cp = ContourPlot[f == g, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 1, 3},
   FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 70];
```

Extract the line coordinates and construct intervals to be used with `NumberLinePlot`:

```
intervals = Map[Interval[First @ CoordinateBounds @ #[[1]]] &]@
   Select[ArcLength[#] > 10^-2 &] @ Cases[Normal @ cp, _Line, All];

Show[cp, 
 NumberLinePlot[intervals, 
   Spacings -> Prepend[3.1]@ConstantArray[.0, Length@intervals]], 
 ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 GridLines -> {Union @ Flatten[Sequence @@@ intervals], None}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use the horizontal coordinate bounds of contour lines to construct the desired lines:

```
lines = Map[Line @ Thread[{First @ CoordinateBounds @ #[[1]], 3.1}] &]@
   Select[ArcLength[#] > 10^-2 &] @ Cases[Normal@cp, Line[x_], All];

Show[cp, 
  Graphics[{CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[.75], AbsoluteThickness[5], 
      RandomColor[], #} & /@ ranges], 
 ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 GridLines -> {Union @ Flatten[ranges[[All, 1, All, 1]]], None}]
```

[image]